# Since vs before, which a conjunction should I use in present or past perfect tense?

Tags: present-perfect, conjunctions, past-perfect

A Conjunction of "since" is used in present perfect tense, and that of "before"  is used in past perfect tense.

for example
A staff working at the company has found the document since his or her boss came back to the company.

A staff working at the company has found the document before his or her boss came back to the company.

I was taught by native-English teacher.

Answer (score 0):

Your teacher is correct although there is an alternative as I explain below.

But to begin with you can't use the construction **A staff**. **Staff** refers to the group of people who are employed somewhere and it takes the plural. So you can refer to **staff** (in general) or **the staff** in particular. In the singular you have to refer to **a member of staff**.

So your sentence would change to a construction like this:

> Staff (working at the company) have found the document since their boss returned.

Note **have found** in the present perfect tense as you state.

With **before**:

> Staff (working at the company) (had) found the document before their boss returned.

**Before** takes either the past perfect or just the past tense. Both are correct and idiomatic. In some sentences choosing one or the other helps to clarify the sequence of events but generally it's optional.